# mod_security and " ModSecurity: Failed deleting collection " error

Tags: mod-security

I've noticed a few days ago the following error in the apache error log :

/[Tue Oct 01 15:11:17 2013] [error] [client ] ModSecurity: Failed deleting collection (name "ip", key "_27752be7ee1615b4d97602d4788e8d99184c9549"): Internal error [hostname "our.hostname.com"] [uri ""] [unique_id "UkrmE8CoAfQAAAuMTmMAAAAK"].

After digging around I found out that it might be related to a bug in mod_security, which is supposedly fixed in the later versions ( we were running 2.6.8 ). I upgraded to the latest stable - 2.7.5.

Unfortunately I am still seeing the error in the log.

I'd be very happy if some one can shed some light on this problem.

PS: we are running CentOS 6.4 on this machine.